# How to find JS code responsible for scrolling after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

In my website I am using many jQuery plugins and I can't sort out the reason why my page is scrolling up to the top after AJAX call.

Sorry, can't paste code cause even I am not sure which plugin is causing the issue and is there any easy way to find why my page is scrolling up after AJAX call.

Test project hosted at https://dev.ther8server.com (Sorry for self-signed SSL)

Search for Brisbane (Have to wait till autocomplete comes and choose Brisbane, Queensland, Australia)

Can leave the dates blank

And in the hotels list, at the ending there is a button "Show More Deals" when I click that its loading 200 more hotels list but unfortunately its scrolling up and people need to scroll down all the way from up.

Is there any easy way to find which element or which plugin is responsible for this scrolling?

I tried in Chrome Inspector and Firebug and couldn't find the correct code.

Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find the click event associated with the "Show More Deals", but might it be that you just have to add `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` to your `<a href="#">` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery.main.js I can see this function.

```
complete: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //remove the loader and move up             
            $('#ajaxload_loader').hide();
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'fast');
        }
```

This line `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'fast');` is the culprit.

Comment: You are genius, great. May I know is there any easy way to find this? Can you please tell me how did you find the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Use chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Are you, after ajax call, removing/replacing html content controls (such as div or table or tr or p) and then adding new html content? if that is the case I would says it is the reason. because it might be reducing the height of your complete web page/document.

Answer (score 0):

Just superficially checked your code, and found that after ajax call you're setting response in as follows:

```
$('#ajaxload_pane').html(data);
```

Instead you should append the data with only the new data something like as follows:

```
$('#ajaxload_pane').append(data);
```

Currently it seem you're fetching the whole list again, the ajax call should return only the new entries of hotels.